# splitPinCodes.split(',') is giving error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am getting error while validating the input.
im getting 6 digit zipcode separated by comma in input text area.
i applied ng-change="convertToArray()" (angular methode)on input text area.

when i entered more than 6 digit without comma(,) it gives error

HTML FILE

```js
$scope.convertToArray=function(){
  var splitPinCodes = $scope.cluster.pincode;
  $scope.toArray = splitPinCodes.split(',');
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="page page-tasks ng-scope main-div ">
 <div class=" callout-elem-info ng-scope cntrl-div"
  data-ng-controller="mobilizationsettings">
  <form name="ClusterInfoForm" class="add-task table form-validate" novalidate>
   <div class="ng-scope left-div">

    <div layout layout-sm="column">
     <h3>Cluster No.1</h3>

     <md-input-container flex class="clusterName">
     <label>Cluster Name</label> <input id="inputCLusterName"
      ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" type="text" ng-model="cluster.Name"
      maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter Cluster Name"
      class="form-control required" required /> </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <div layout layout-sm="column">
     <md-input-container flex> <label>Cluster
      PinCodes</label> <input id="inputCLusterPincodes"
      ng-pattern="/^[1-9][0-9]{5}(?:,[1-9][0-9]{5})*$/" type="text"
      ng-model="cluster.pincode" ng-change="convertToArray()"
      placeholder="Enter Cluster PinCode" class="form-control " /> </md-input-container>

     <div class="addPinCode-div">
      <md-button required ng-model="newEntry" 
       class="btn-width-medium md-raised md-primary btn-lg md-button md-default-theme md-button addPinCodeButton"
       ng-click="addNewPinCode($data,$event)"> ADD
      PINCODE(S) </md-button>
     </div>
     &nbsp;
    </div>
```

so please help me with other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If the delimiter is not found, split does nothing. Rewrite as this and it should work:

```
$scope.convertToArray=function(){
     if($scope.cluster.pincode.indexOf(',')==-1){
         $scope.toArray = [$scope.cluster.pincode];
     }else{
    var splitPinCodes = $scope.cluster.pincode;
        $scope.toArray = splitPinCodes.split(',');
     }
}
```

EDIT :

> when I entered more than 6 digit without comma(,) it gives error

Yes this is what your ng-pattern is saying : "crashing if more than 6 character without comma".

Comment: i am taking 6 digit comma separated input
if i enter more than 6 digit without comma....now its giving error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Comment: You had to change the ng-pattern too. And maybe test if the value is defined. I'm not sure but if you're expression is invalid it's possible that ng-change is called with your value set to undefined.